# How do i array push my tables into one array? php

Tags: php, arrays, list

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT O.OrderDate, P.prodID, P.prodName, PO.PurchaseQty FROM Customer C, Orders O, Product P, ProductOrder PO WHERE P.prodID = PO.prodID AND PO.OrderID = O.OrderID AND O.custID = C.custID AND C.custID =  'C1000';")) {

//$response["orderhistory"] = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $orderhistory= array();
    $Orders["OrderDate"] = $row["OrderDate"];
    $Product["prodID"] = $row["prodID"];
    $Product["prodName"] = $row["prodName"];

$ProductOrder["PurchaseQty"] = $row["PurchaseQty"];


     // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response,$Orders,$Product,$ProductOrder);
}



// success
//$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

**Output:**

```
[{"OrderDate":"2015-12-11"},{"prodID":"SF10W","prodName":"Cordless Drill Driver"},{"PurchaseQty":"4"}
```

**The output i want :**

```
"{OrderDate":"2015-12-11",SF10W","prodName":"Cordless Drill Driver","PurchaseQty":"4"}
```

PS:This is my android assignment and there is some function i need to use php function, and i have never study in php before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$row = array(
    "OrderDate" => '2015-12-11',
    "prodID" => 'SF10W"',
    "prodName" => 'Cordless Drill Driver',
    "PurchaseQty" => '4'
);

$response = array(
    "OrderDate" => $row["OrderDate"],
    "prodID" => $row["prodID"],
    "prodName" => $row["prodName"],
    "PurchaseQty" => $row["PurchaseQty"]
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

You can check it here: https://eval.in/484082. Also check [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it help! 
but the display can be possible similar to this example?
http://rexldomain.netau.net/select_course.php
because the android studio only accept this certain format

Comment: your output is 
  ``[{"OrderDate":"2015-12-11","prodID":"SF10W\"","prodName":"Cordless Drill Driver","PurchaseQty":"4"}]``  
but my desired output is ``[{"OrderDate":"2015-12-11","prodID":"SF10W","prodName":"Cordless Drill Driver","PurchaseQty":"4"}, {"OrderDate":"2015-12-11","prodID":"SF10W\"","prodName":"Cordless Drill Driver","PurchaseQty":"4"}]``
android studio only accept the format if [ {object1}, {object2} ] :(

Comment: Thank you! for saving my time to complete my assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT O.OrderDate, P.prodID, P.prodName, PO.PurchaseQty FROM Customer C, Orders O, Product P, ProductOrder PO WHERE P.prodID = PO.prodID AND PO.OrderID = O.OrderID AND O.custID = C.custID AND C.custID =  'C1000';")) {

//$response["orderhistory"] = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $orderhistory= array();
    //$Orders["OrderDate"] = $row["OrderDate"];
    //$Product["prodID"] = $row["prodID"];
    //$Product["prodName"] = $row["prodName"];

//$ProductOrder["PurchaseQty"] = $row["PurchaseQty"];


     // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response,$row["OrderDate"],$row["prodID"],$row["prodName"], $row["PurchaseQty"]);
}



// success
//$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

pass variable in array_push topush in same array.

Comment: **["2015-12-11","SF10W","Cordless Drill Driver","4","2015-12-11","SF11W","Screw Driver","5"]**
this is my current output,
is there anyway to make the output become like this?
(if my date is same)
**{"2015-12-11","SF10W","Cordless Drill Driver","4"}, {"2015-12-11","SF11W","Screw Driver","5"}**

Comment: You have to use in_array function to check date is exist or not in exist the you have to push it in array format

Comment: but i just want it to printout in another array even it is same date... is there a way to show it?